# Codecademy Functions, Part I PHP

Tags: php, function, parsing

im starting to learn PHP through Codecademy.
andd i got a Parse error on line 7
I look it up on the web and i tried with and without the quotes and it doesn't work.
Someone could help me find out what is wrong, please?
Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<p>
<?php
// Create an array and push on the names
// of your closest family and friends
$closefriends = array ("Cessie","Lulu","Tutur",) ;
int  array_push("Cessie","Lulu","Tutur",) ;
sort ( $closefriends );
// Sort the list

// Randomly select a winner!

// Print the winner's name in ALL CAPS
?>
</p>
```

Comment: Would you like to tidy up that code asmple or does it really look like that

Comment: What is the `enter code here` doing in there?

Comment: Compare your code to the example code in the tutorial. **They wont match**

Comment: And please take a look at the syntax of the `array_push()` function, the first argument needs to be an array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: `enter code here doesn't really belong there

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end of the array, after "Tutur"

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you are asking for.

```
<?php

  // Create an array and push on the names
  // of your closest family and friends

  $closefriends = array () ;
  array_push($closefriends,"Cessie","Lulu","Tutur");

  // Sort the list
  sort( $closefriends );

  // Randomly select a winner!
  $rand_friend = array_rand($closefriends, 1);

  // Print the winner's name in ALL CAPS
  $str = strtoupper($closefriends[$rand_friend]);
  echo $str;

?>
```

At the start of the code you are creating an array to store you values, example: "Cessie", "Lulu","tutur".

*Example:* `$YourarrayName = array();`

then you have the array_push() treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array.This also increases the length of the array.

*Example:* `array_push('the array you want to add to', the values you wanted added, "value", "value")`

Sorting the array, this is done with the sort() function. This function sorts an array, where the elements will be arranged from lowest to highest when this function has completed.

*Example* `sort('name_of_array_to_be_sorted');`

To randomly select and element from the sorted array you use the array_rand() function.This picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns the key (or keys) of the random entries. then you just assigned the value that was picked at random to a variable.

*Example:* `$yourVariable = array_rand('YourArrayName', 'the number of random items you want');`

Then to the last part of all this you are asked to print the winner to all upper case letter. This is just a simple pass to the strtoupper() function. Really all it does is returns a string, with all alphabetic characters converted to uppercase.

then you just use and echo statement to print the final value out.

Comment: Thank you  a lot, can you  explain me more about the code and how can i learn more about the syntax,  it's killing me.

Comment: Do you mean PHP all together or just the code above?

Comment: @Jean-Huguesruby if this is the answer you are looking for please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I mean the code

Answer (score -2):

- When defining an Array, dont use a comma after the last item.
- remove `enter code here`int
- remove the array_push, it has syntax errors and you already have those values in your array